# mysqli returns all identical records

Tags: php, mysqli

The following code is supposed to retrieve all the records from a table and return them to an array.  It does return correct number of records however all records are identical.  Does anyone have a clue what the problem is?

```
function list_book() {
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$conn =  mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, 'db') or die('Could Not Connect' . mysql_error());
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM book")) {
    $stmt->bind_result($r['book_id'], $r['book_title']);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        exit();
    }
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $book[] = $r;
    }
    print_r($book);     //**** added purposely to examine the content of the array
    exit();

    return $book;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Parameters must be bound AFTER the statement is executed ... See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Also, I don't know if you can bind to elements of an array ...

Try this in your if statement ...

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    exit();
}

$stmt->bind_result($book_id, $book_title);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $book[] = array($book_id, $book_title);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. it does return three different records (that's correct) but it doesn't return column name whereas the one I posted also returned three records with column name but all of them are the last record.

Comment: Thanks.  I also tried to move parameters binding after the execution statement and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ugly mysqli.
Use some helper class that can do all the job in 2 lines, luke [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) does

```
function list_book() {
    global $db; // NEVER connect in the function, connect once and then use ONE connection
    return $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM book");
}
```

Or at least use PDO, if you want to stick with raw API.
But forget mysqli, it's unusable.

Comment: Sorry, even though I'm having a hard time to learn mysqli but I have no choice other than to conform to project standard. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that there is only ONE array `$r`. Each time you call `$stmt->fetch()`, the parameters of this array are just overwritten, and you append it again to your `$book`-array.

**One possible Solution:** (not necessarily the nicest one)

```
$stmt->bind_result($book_id, $book_title);
...
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $book[] = array($book_id, $book_title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Same result as the solution provided by dleiftah.  It does return 3 different records but the column name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the problem by adding the following inside the while loop.  Thanks for everyone's contribution!!! :)

```
foreach( $r as $key=>$value ) {
    $row_tmb[ $key ] = $value;
}

$book[] = $row_tmb;
```

Comment: Just curious what tmb of $row_tmb would stand for because this snippet was copied from php official website.

Answer (score -1):

Does the table have duplicate records?

If so, slightly modified SQL may help, for example:
`SELECT DISTINCT book_id, book_title FROM book`

And rather than an explicit 'bind', maybe `$r = $stmt` -> `fetch_assoc()`

Then you can collect `$r['book_title']` (or whatever field) to your array.

Comment: No, there are three different records.